# Copy and then insert data from one cell in a table to another cell in that table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server database table and it has a field that its name is PersonPhoto (its data is binary picture) and I need to insert PersonPhoto from person with `personCode=11` to field of PersonPhoto for another Person with `personCode=5`. How can I do this with T-SQL?

Comment: Please provide sample data, expected results and attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
Update Person
Set PersonPhoto = (Select Top(1) PersonPhoto From Person where pesronCode = 11)
Where pesronCode=5
```

Also, You can use variable like this :

```
Declare @PersonPhoto as Varbinary(Max)
```

Save to variable then use it

Comment: Thank you, I did this command and it inserted <Binary data> in PersonPhoto but I do not see any picture when I run my application

Comment: Use SSMS Booster, the Tool show you what it really is inside the field. (Because there is nothing wrong with T-SQL Code)